# Firestore Security Rules, allow read and write if WEB_API_KEY is in the Https request

Tags: firebase, https, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, google-apis-explorer

I am sending GET, POST, PATCH and DELETE requests to Firestore using HttpsURLConnection.

```
private static final String REST_HEADER = "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/[my project id]/databases/(default)/documents/";


        // Build URL
        String FirestoreURL = REST_HEADER + [my document path] + "?key=" + [my web api key];

        // Create URL
        URL cloudFirestoreEndPoint = new URL(FirestoreURL);

        // Create connection
        myHttpsConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) cloudFirestoreEndPoint.openConnection();

        // Set Request Method
        myHttpsConnection.setRequestMethod("PATCH");

        // Set Writable
        myHttpsConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        // Set Https Connection properties
        myHttpsConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        // Create output stream linked to our https connection
        OutputStreamWriter streamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(myHttpsConnection.getOutputStream());

        // Write to buffer
        streamWriter.write([my json]);

        // Send out the buffer
        streamWriter.flush();

        // Close the stream
        streamWriter.close();

        // disconnect
        myHttpsConnection.disconnect();
```

I would like to know how to set my Firestore database rule so that any read & write request that contains the right "?key="[my web api key] is allowed.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {  
     match /{document=**} {
       allow read, write: if request == 'MY WEB API KEY???';
     }
  }
}
```

How would you go about writing that in Firestore?

Comment: I also have the same problem. did you solve this yet?

Comment: Yes I have updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I have solved the problem. You send a request for a token at the googleapis end point. You will receive a payload containing a long key that you then have to add to all your path, get, post, ... request.

Here is the request to get the token

```
        // Build URL
        String authenticationURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty";

        if(methodType_.equals("SIGN_UP")){
            authenticationURL = authenticationURL + "/signupNewUser";
        }else if(methodType_.equals("SIGN_IN")){
            authenticationURL = authenticationURL + "/verifyPassword";
        }else{
            return null;
        }
        authenticationURL = authenticationURL + "?key=" + webApiKey_;

        // Create URL
        URL endPointURL = new URL(authenticationURL);

        // Create connection
        myHttpsConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) endPointURL.openConnection();

        // Set Request Method
        myHttpsConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        // Set Writable
        myHttpsConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        // Set Https Connection properties
        myHttpsConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        // Generate JSON from the data
        String myJSON_str = "{\"email\":\"" + email,\"password\":\"" +
                password_ + "\",\"returnSecureToken\":true}";

        JSONObject myJSON = new JSONObject(myJSON_str);

        // Create output stream linked to our https connection
        OutputStreamWriter streamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(myHttpsConnection.getOutputStream());

        // Write to buffer
        streamWriter.write(myJSON.toString());

        // Send out the buffer
        streamWriter.flush();

        // Close the stream
        streamWriter.close();

        // Get Response Code
        myResponseCode = myHttpsConnection.getResponseCode();

        // If connection successful
        if (myResponseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

            // Get Input Stream
            InputStream streamReader = myHttpsConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader responseBodyReader = new InputStreamReader(streamReader, "UTF-8");

            // Buffer the inputstream
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(responseBodyReader);

            // Create JsonReader from input stream
            JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(br);

            // My custom method to convert a JSON to a readable thing
            ArrayList<Field_Value> myFields = JSON_Methods.convertFirestoreJSON(jsonReader);

            // Close Streams
            jsonReader.close();
            br.close();
            responseBodyReader.close();
            streamReader.close();

            // Get The IdToken Field
            idToken_ = Field_Value.getFieldValue(myFields,"idToken");

        }
```

After you add this to all your get, patch, post.. requests,

```
   // Set Authorization header
        myHttpsConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + idToken_);
```

Comment: How to verify the key in firestore security rules?